# Compare string "A" to string "B" in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a function in Coldfusion that will take 2 strings and figure out which is the 'higher' alphabetically . So if I had "Daniel" and "John", it would return Daniel?

Comment: "So if I had "Daniel" and "John", it would return Daniel?" - Em... Maybe John?

Comment: Do you mean length? No string can be higher then another.

Comment: By higher i mean higher alphabetically, does that make any sense. IE D is higher than J

Comment: Go to a search engine, enter "[coldfusion compare two strings](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=coldfusion+compare+two+strings)" and look at the first result?

Comment: Tried it. Not what I want

Comment: J would be higher then D in the alphabet

Comment: Um, either it _is_ what you want, or you're incorrectly describing your problem.

Comment: Or you are misunderstanding. Bit of both i think. If i had 'A' and 'C' Id like to know which one is the 'highest' alphabetically. I would think that was A. Is there any function that will do this is my question.

Comment: Not really. How you would deal with this would depend on how you get your data. If they are already in an array or query then you can sort these

Comment: The `compare` function does _exactly_ what you've asked for - it compares the ASCII char codes (which are alphabetically arranged) and returns an appropriate result. If you want something different you need to edit your question to clearly state what that is.

Comment: Ah maybe compare does. The docs use language like "if string1 is less than string2" when describing the return from the compare function so i thought it was doing a length based comparison. Not a hard mistake to make, those docs arent fantastic

Comment: Also confusing the issue is that the term, 'higher alphabetically' is more ambiguous than I thought.

Comment: Peter is right, the `compare()` function is exactly what you want. Your terminology of Daniel being higher than John is what's not quite correct. You're evaluating ASCII values, so D (68) is actually lower than J (74). Which brings up another caveat. You should normalize the case before doing your comparison. For example, lower case d has an ASCII value of 100, higher than upper case J (74)

Comment: Then you might find this information handy.  http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your strings into an array then use arraySort(). *(example not tested)*

```
var names = ['Daniel', 'John'];
arraySort( names, 'textnocase' );
writeOutput(names[1]);
```

Comment: That would do. Didn't think of that. Thanks

Comment: There's also `ListSort()`.

Comment: `compare()` would be a better choice.